# ExtJS 4 MVC - how to load only current controller and its related data?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, controller, extjs4

as we know, Ext.application has 'controllers' property/config/option (call it whatever you like). So we can give what controllers we have. And then, for controllers we can specify which views do they have.

My question is, is there a way to let the Ext application know about current controller/action pair depending on URL (just the way it is done in e.g. PHP - Zend, Code Igniter frameworks) ?
(to not have each and every controller, view in respective arrays loaded and executed)

currently I'm using my own solution. I use this code in app.js file:

```
url = document.URL.split("/");
var contreollers = [];
var views = [];

if( url.length <= 4 ){

controllers = ['index'];
views = ['index/index'];
}
else{

if( document.URL.indexOf('index.php') >= 0 ){

controllerPos = 4;
}
else{

controllerPos = 3;
}

controllers = [url[controllerPos]];

if( url.length > controllerPos+1 ){

views = [url[controllerPos]+'/'+url[controllerPos+1]];
}
else{

views = [url[controllerPos]+'/index'];
}
}
```

Best,
Vahagn

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the files to load that you need, you want to look into Dynamic Loading, about 1/5 of the way down the page on the [Sencha Blog](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system).

You might have to switch to the MVC structure that Sencha has suggested we use for Ext JS 4. You can find a few guides related to MVC structure and App Architecture in the [Sencha Doc Guides](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide).